# Lambda to trigger a DLT pipeline

Tags: databricks, delta-live-tables

I have a source file that I load into S3 as a delta file. I can attach a lambda trigger to the file. Is there a way to trigger a DLT pipeline based on the lambda trigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use [DLT REST APIs](https://docs.databricks.com/workflows/delta-live-tables/delta-live-tables-api-guide.html#start-a-pipeline-update) to start *existing* DLT pipeline (it should be pre-created, although you can create it via APIs as well if it doesn't exist yet).  Another approach is to create a Databricks job around DLT pipeline, and then use [Jobs REST API](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html) to trigger that job.